# React material UI table scrolling not smooth when height is set

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

In my app material UI table is used with set height. table needs to show 100 items at least without any pagination.

When I try to scroll to the bottom of the table scrolling is not smooth. Any idea how to improve this?

This is a sample I created from my code.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-9k8gnl?file=Hello.tsx
However in the sample I cant recreate the issue I am facing.

Comment: I went to the toilet for 15 minutes and come back to see, the demo is still loading.

Comment: sorry @NearHuscarl , https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-9k8gnl?file=Hello.tsx this is the file

Comment: I can't help you identify and solve the problem if the stackbliz doesn't have an issue with scrolling though.